# Trying to send ether to multiple addresses

Tags: solidity, web3js

Trying to send ether to multiple addresses. For the first address the transaction succeeded but for the rest of the addresses it is showing "transaction underpriced". Below is the code attached. I have tried changing the gas price, but that didn't work.

```
var ad = ['0x66622d1E25cca28454c2e2b4726c05b27B094f68', '0x2F55E7E8Af52dC91715670e579c64A2a84d21A50', '0xd2a56Eb440725BAf29eE1cfA7899c12Ef1BC642D'];

function newfunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < ad.length; i++) {
        sendRaw(rawTx);
        var rawTx = {
            nonce: web3.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)),
            gasLimit: web3.toHex(21000),
            gasPrice: web3.eth.gasPrice.toNumber() * 1.40,
            to: ad[i],
            value: web3.toHex(web3.toBigNumber(10000000000000000))
        };
    }
}
```

Attached is the error [image: error code is attached]

Comment: In `nonce` value, you are entering the same value all time?

Comment: @MaheshRajput   i am getting the nonce value using "web3.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address))". should i add "+i" so that it will increase the nonce value by 1 for each addresses in array?(i tried but again i got the error "transaction underpriced" and my first transaction also didnt succeded this time)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same nonce for every transaction, so only one can succeed. Try incrementing the nonce each time. (Also, I'm not sure why the `sendRaw` call was above the assignment to `rawTx`. I moved it below.)

```
function newfunction() {
  var startingNonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address);
  for (var i = 0; i < ad.length; i++) {
    var rawTx = {
      nonce: startingNonce + i,
      gasLimit: web3.toHex(21000),
      gasPrice: web3.eth.gasPrice.toNumber() * 1.40,
      to: ad[i],
      value: web3.toHex(web3.toBigNumber(10000000000000000))
    };
    sendRaw(rawTx);
  }
}
```